# String acting abnormally in a For Each loop in VBA code in MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, vba

Okay so I started with [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391991/for-each-not-working-properly-in-vba-code) and have made a lot of changes to the code based on suggestions from this site and others so I figured I should create a new question.

Even though my code is shorter and more efficient the same problem persists; I am using a string called strSQL that contains and INSERT statement that I want executed.  I have a FOR EACH loop that goes through each control on my MSAcess form (ensures they are either a text box, drop down list or checkbox) and determines if the field has been changed.  If it has it generates a query string to log the change -- and stores it in strSQL.

The problem is that the same query is being executed again and again.  I have added a DEBUG.PRINT statement before and after the line that executes the query string and the debugger shows that the string has CHANGED!  Yes you read that right, this seems to be impossible but I have taken screenshots.

Firstly my code:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim C As Control
    For Each C In Controls
        Select Case C.ControlType
            Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acCheckBox
                Dim strOriginalValue, strCurrentValue, strSQL As String

                strOriginalValue = IIf(IsNull(C.OldValue), "", IIf(C.OldValue = vbTrue Or C.OldValue = vbFalse, IIf(C.OldValue = vbTrue, "Yes", "No"), C.OldValue))
                strCurrentValue = IIf(IsNull(C.Value), "", IIf(C.Value = vbTrue Or C.Value = vbFalse, IIf(C.Value = vbTrue, "Yes", "No"), C.Value))

                If strOriginalValue <> strCurrentValue Then
                    strSQL = "INSERT INTO fringefestival_changes (change_time,change_admin,action_taken,user_affected,year_affected,field_affected,type_affected,old_value,new_value) VALUES (NOW(),'" & ThisUserName() & "','Edit'," & [id] & ",0,'" & C.ControlSource & "','Administrator','" & Replace(strOriginalValue, "'", "") & "','" & Replace(strCurrentValue, "'", "") & "')"
                    Debug.Print "Before: " & strSQL
                    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
                    Debug.Print "After: " & strSQL
                End If
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Here is the results of the debugger:

```
Before: INSERT INTO fringefestival_changes (change_time,change_admin,action_taken,user_affected,year_affected,field_affected,type_affected,old_value,new_value) VALUES (NOW(),'ajohnson','Edit',3,0,'indoor_performers_tab','Administrator','No','Yes')
After: INSERT INTO fringefestival_changes (change_time,change_admin,action_taken,user_affected,year_affected,field_affected,type_affected,old_value,new_value) VALUES (NOW(),'ajohnson','Edit',3,0,'indoor_performers_tab','Administrator','No','Yes')
Before: INSERT INTO fringefestival_changes (change_time,change_admin,action_taken,user_affected,year_affected,field_affected,type_affected,old_value,new_value) VALUES (NOW(),'ajohnson','Edit',3,0,'volunteers_tab','Administrator','No','Yes')
After: INSERT INTO fringefestival_changes (change_time,change_admin,action_taken,user_affected,year_affected,field_affected,type_affected,old_value,new_value) VALUES (NOW(),'ajohnson','Edit',3,0,'volunteers_tab','Administrator','No','Yes')
```

Secondly my screenshots...  firstly the debugger: [1](http://www.andrew-g-johnson.com/access1.jpg) & [2](http://www.andrew-g-johnson.com/access2.jpg) and secondly the results: [here](http://www.andrew-g-johnson.com/access3.jpg) -- note that the debugger is too wide so I took two screenshots and the results have a row colored out as it has nothing to do with this problem.

Note that the only column that should be different in the example I gave should be the "field_affected" column.

I am at a complete loss, I have no idea why it would output the correct string to the debugger and execute something else.

**EDIT: Before using CurrentDb.Execute, I was using DoCmd.RunSQL but this required me to disable and then re-enable warnings.  Since the result was the same for both (same error) I used the one line solution instead of the three line solution.**

**UPDATE: Shoutout to [shahkalpesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396848/string-acting-abnormally-in-a-for-each-loop-in-vba-code-in-msaccess#396989) for helping me realize that the data is indeed being inserted correctly and I can see it in SQL Server's management studio but MS Access is still displaying it incorrectly... the question is why?**

**FINAL EDIT: Fixed by adding an identity/auto-increment integer column to the table, I suspect that the lack of differing field values was confusing MSAccess (although it really has no reason to) -- the morale here is M$ is stupid**

Comment: Please point out exactly where there is a difference in the before and after SQL strings. You have two before and after sets, and these are different to each other, but the befores are the same as the afters, as far as I can see.

Comment: PS You can simplify:                     strOriginalValue = IIf(C.OldValue = vbTrue Or C.OldValue = vbFalse, _
                    Format(C.OldValue, "Yes/No"), Nz(C.OldValue, ""))

Comment: Please do not use screen shots, please show in your text the difference between before and after that concerns you - I can only see SQL output as requested in the code.

Comment: Remou - results have been added as text

Comment: Where is the difference that concerns you? I cannot see anything wrong, the SQL is executing as expected. What did you want to happen?

Comment: There should be 2 queries executed; the first with "indoor_performers_tab" as its "field_affected" value and the second with "volunteers_tab" as the value.  They are both showing up as "indoor_performers_tab".  Note that this example only has 2 queries, if I do 5 or more it acts the same.

Comment: Change to show error: CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

Comment: I'm still not seeing the difference.

Comment: So you weren't seeing your new records in the audit table? Yeah, you have to have a primary key or Access freaks.

Comment: I was seeing them, but if I had two rows that were virtually identical and inserted at nearly the same time they would appear 100& identical in the returned results.

Answer (score 1):

Is the form in question bound to a datasource? This is the most common way that Access would be used, and if it were you probbaly wouldn't need to update via SQL.

Form_BeforeUpdate() is usually used when a form is bound to a datasource. You wouldn't normally use this event to determine if controls' values have changed and need writing back to the DB...

Comment: Yes I am only using MSAccess as a front end -- all data is stored on a SQL Server database.  What would you suggest I do in this situation?

Comment: Also I am using ODBC to connect to the database if that wasn't already apparent...

Comment: If the form and its controls are bound to a datasource (which is in term a query based on your linked tables), you probably don't need to write any code (unless you want to intercept and chnage values before writing) in order to save changed info...

Comment: You're saying I should use a trigger I assume.  I originally went down that path but decided against it as I need to log the active directory username of the person making the change (return value of ThisUserName()) and couldn't do that via a trigger.

Comment: This is an admin module for a local festival.  If changes are made to performers,shows,etc the head admin would like to see who exactly made the change and what the change was -- a.k.a. old/new values

Comment: If each user is connecting as thier logon Windows principle (rather than using a pooled connection string) you could use a trigger with  TSQL's SUSER_NAME(). But if you're using a shared connection that's obviously no good...

Comment: It is no good, believe me when I say I've walked down the same path you are walking now :)

Comment: So you are using a pooled connection?

Comment: It really makes no sense to not use unbound forms with ODBC data sources. You might as well program in plain VB if you're not using bound forms/controls.

Answer (score 1):

If you can goto the specific SQL Server table (using Query Analyzer or Enterprise Mgr) & see whether it works as you expect. I am doubting that linked table in VBA might be showing you incorrect picture.

Edit: If you have SQL Profiler, see what is being executed there to confirm your doubt of the same query getting executed.

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right.  If I go right into SQL Server the data is correct.  I actually laughed out loud when I saw this, now the question is: why doesn't it display properly in MS Access?

Comment: Not sure about that part. But, I have observed this even when working inside Access. And, I thought of writing it after your reply of query being printed in Debug window correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

You run those querys against currentdb (wich I assume is the access-db) but are in fact using a SQL server database where you want the changes to happend?

Are those tables in the sql server linked to tables in the access-db or what method are you using?

Comment: Yes they are linked tables to the SQL Server database.

Comment: Are you sure that the links points to the database you think? I have many times made the mistake (when switching between different dev/deploy-servers) that looking in wrong database, thinking Im working on my local DB but actually running against another.

Comment: No I am sure, not only is there only one database running this schema but even if I was connecting to the wrong one I would still not be having this error because of it.

Comment: It "could" manifest itself like that if the "other" db has only those two records already and never being updated only shows them.. But OK, if you ruled that out then we have to check other possibilities

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the table for broken triggers? It's a long shot, but some very very odd problems have been caused by bad/broken triggers before, and they're hard to understand before you notice the trigger...

Comment: No triggers on this entire database, but a valid suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding an auto-incrementing integer primary key column to the changes table.

Silly Access...

Comment: No, silly Andrew G. Johnson for not knowing how to design an Access application. If you gave any thought to how ODBC has to work, you'd realize that a primary key is essential on all tables, and that a time stamp field is required to keep data in a bound form refreshed.

Comment: Silly ODBC* -- why do you think its intelligent to have all these extra unneeded worries?

Answer (score -1):

Ah, you're using SQL Server too. I have had very good luck with using triggers to audit data changes behind Access. There are a couple of quirks, but linking the tables via ODBC using trusted authentication makes it very easy.

OK, so you can't or don't want to use triggers. When front-ending SQL with Access, I usually use ADO objects in my VBA code for this sort of thing. Linked tables with ODBC are great for bound forms, but nothing beats ADO for going directly to the SQL Server.

Would you like more information about linking the tables using trusted authentication or help with using ADO to do the work with SQL Server?

Answer (score -1):

I have to say the discussion around this question drives me crazy. With ODBC linked tables, you start with bound forms. There is simply no reason to be using pooled connections. If you are hostile to the Access implementation of how to do these things STOP USING ACCESS.